# Primefaces blockUI and composition

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, composite-component

I'm using JSF 2.2, PF 5.3 and GlassFish 4.1.1.

I'm trying to centralize the blockUI content in my web application.
here the code of the my custom blockUI

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
  xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="block" type="java.lang.String"/>
    <cc:attribute name="trigger" type="java.lang.String"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <p:blockUI block="#{cc.attrs.block}" trigger="#{cc.attrs.trigger}">
        LOADING<br />
        <p:graphicImage library="images" name="ajax-loader.gif"/>
    </p:blockUI>
</cc:implementation>
```

and here the code in which I'm trying to apply this one

```
<h:form>
...
...

<p:dataTable id="myTable">
  <p:column headerText="actions">
    <p:commandButton class="triggerableFromBlockUI" action="#{action1}"/>
    <p:commandButton class="triggerableFromBlockUI" action="#{action2}"/>
  </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

...
...
<myTag:blockUI block="myTable" trigger="@(.triggerableFromBlockUI)"/>
</h:form>
```

but I see the following error

```
Cannot find component for expression "myTable".
```

If I use directly the p:blockUI all is working. Can you help me?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using cc everywhere? why not just put your block in a fragment and ui:include in the common layout? - dont get me wrong, componsite components are great, but not sure why you need it for this scenario if you just auto include in the layout once. CC is generally if you manually are placing on several pages.

Comment: I guess we need to see yuor folder structure as well / file names etc. please provide

Comment: Hi VeenarM, You're true, and was my first idea. But I think is a little bit silly to lost the centralization of the component. For example for reusing some attributes of the tag.  At the moment I don't have this need, but if I place 500 blockUI's and then I need to make some modification in all of them, I will lose a lot of time and will be not a safe operation(from the human point of view), and will be very complicated to test every blockUI.

Comment: Hi VeenarM, my folder structure follows the standard. I've the src/main/webapp/pageContainingMyTag.xhtml and src/main/webapp/resources/customTags/blockUI.xhtml for my custom tag. The ns inside the page is xmlns:cvl="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite/customTags"

Comment: I didn't realise you were putting block ui's on 'specific components' ie data tables. I've only ever seen/ujsed a block ui to block the entire page whilst something is occuring/waiting for a response. - did you account for the extra layer from resources in your including? ie customTags/blockUi

Comment: If you could paste more code, would be good at the moment its just stabbing in the dark to identify the issue without seeing everything.

Comment: Which code should be useful? At the moment I've posted all the code that is involved in the problem(I hope)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115576/discussion-between-veenarm-and-gavi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the solution found in the Prime Faces Forum

```
<myTag:blockUI block="@form:myTable" trigger="@(.triggerableFromBlockUI)"/>
```